# Save string as local file.txt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to save a string to a local file.txt

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

and this js

```
var string = 'ThisIsMyString';
var a = '<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,'+ string + '">text file</a>';
$('.content').append(a);
```

As you can see the text 'ThisIsMyString' from var a gets saved in the file just as i wanted but the problem is that if you inspect the  element you will be able to see my text inside the anchor tag.

You can check it here.
http://jsfiddle.net/VBJ9h/2389/

The question is, is there any way hide the content of the file from the a tag?

Comment: No, none at all. The content has to be accessible to the client for it to be read.

Comment: What is source of string? numerous ways you could encode/decode it so user can't read it directly , or store it as a property of element until user clicks on it

Comment: At some point though it would need to be exposed

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to hide content from the Developer Console like that.

If you want to request something without revealing an explicit link you should consider using an ajax request, and some programming language to provide a back-end for sending the file to the request.